# Beautiful Soup "not supported" Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup

I am working in python on a GAE app. Beautiful soup, which the app uses, works fine on my dev server locally. When I try and upload it to google's servers however, I get the following error: "Error parsing yaml file: the library "bs4" is not supported".

I am not sure how to fix this. Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

File Structure:

app.yaml
main.py
static(DIR)
templates(DIR)
bs4(DIR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said what you've tried to do, but it sounds like you've put `bs4` into the `libraries` section of app.yaml. That's only for libraries that are included in GAE itself (see [the list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)): if you want to use BS4, you should include it within your application bundle that you upload to GAE.

Comment: I have added BS4 folder in my app files that I am trying to upload. It resides in the same directory as my app.yaml. How should I change this?

Comment: You don't need to change anything, that is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Before I had the BS4 library mentioned in my app.yaml. This is wrong as it is not supported by GAE out of the box. Once I removed this, it worked since the BS4 folder was already included in its entirety in my app i was actually uploading. Just in case anyone else has this issue going forward.

Answer (score 0):

It seems uploading the whole directory where the `bs4` module resides in to the GAE app folder would work.